# Symfony2 Form Builder Entity Type Selected Value

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I am noop in symfony 2. Could someone help me for the symfony2 form type builder?

I have a form with `Product` Entity and I want to use selectbox in the form to list all user in my `User` Entity. When I created form with `Product` details, all inputs are ok without `userid`. User selectbox has not selected value which come from `Product` Entity with `userId`.

```php
namespace ATL\ProductBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductGeneralType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){       
            $builder->add("name", null, array(
                "label" => "Name",
                "required" => true,
                "attr" => array(
                    "class" => "span5",
                )
            ))->add("description",null,array(
                "label" => "Description",
                "required" => true,
                "attr" => array(
                    "class" => "span8"
                )
            ))->add("visible",null,array(
                "label" => "Visible"
            ))->add("userId","entity",array(
                "label" => "User",
                "class" => "ATLUserBundle:User",
                "query_builder" => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder("u")->where("u.enabled = 1")->orderBy("u.username", "ASC");
                },
            ));
    }

    public function getName(){
        return "product";
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            "data_class" => "ATL\ProductBundle\Entity\Product"
        ));
    }   
}
```

`Name`, `Description` and `Visible` are ok and get from database. But `User` was not selected with `userId` from the `Product` Entity. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, in my `Product` entity, my mapped name of `User` entity is `users`. I changed the `userId` to `users`, and it fixed.